# BizTalk 2016 WCF-SAP warning

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

When receiving iDOCS from SAP with BizTalk 2016 (Nco) we sometimes get the following warning message.

> The adapter "WCF-SAP" raised an error message. Details "System.ArgumentException: "typeName" can't be null or empty
>   Parameter name: typeName
>      at Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.Design.AdapterAsyncResult.End()
>      at Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.Channels.AdapterReplyChannel.EndTryReceiveRequest(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
>      at Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.LayeredInboundChannel`1.System.ServiceModel.Channels.IReplyChannel.EndTryReceiveRequest(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& context)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)".

This blocks the incoming idoc for processing in BizTalk. After some analysis we can't really link it to a specific idoc type.
It seems to happen on different idoc types and not all the time.

Does somebody have any clue what could be wrong here? Google is not my friend for this one. :-)

We are using Nco 3019 x64

Comment: What Feature Pack or Cumulative Update are installed?

Comment: We have FP3 installed, so that should include CU5. And yes, we already tried the hotfix. :-)

Comment: As a temporary fix we reverted back to ClassicRfc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on 2016 CU5 then you might look into this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345385/biztalk-server-2016-cu5-breaks-sap-nco-receive-adapter-functionality

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Microsoft made a fix for it. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4528784/fix-microsoft-biztalk-server-wcf-sap-adapter-nco-cannot-handle-strong